# GNU parallel output progress while output to file

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a simple bash script to run:

```
cat full_path.csv | parallel --progress -j +0 'echo -n {},; pdfgrep -c [^_] {};' > path_count.csv
```

Parallel's progress indicator `"--progress"`, writes into the file `path_count.csv`. I only want `echo {}` and `pdfgrep {}` to write to the file, while showing `--progress` output to screen.

If I do :

```
cat full_path.csv | parallel --progress -j +0  'echo -n {},>>path_count.csv; pdfgrep -c [^_] {}>>path_count.csv;'
```

the file path_count is still garbled with progress.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks
Alvin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you see is not what GNU Parallel is designed to do: --progress is normally sent to STDERR and not to STDOUT for exactly that reason:

```
$ seq 3 | bin/parallel --progress echo {} >/tmp/out

Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 8 / 3

Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
local:0/3/100%/0.0s
$ cat /tmp/out
1
2
3
```

Has there been local modifications of GNU Parallel? Can you reproduce the issue on other systems?

PS: instead of 'echo -n' why to try: --tag

Comment: Thanks, I am really not sure how tag replaces echo -n {}. Maybe an example with my script?

Comment: --tag will add the sequence number to the start of the output line delimited by a tab, so in your case, you might see in your target file (escaped characters because no newlines in comments):


1 \t output,goes,here \n 2 \t more,output,here

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect it completely within the subshell using exec:

```
: > path_count.csv  ## truncate file
cat full_path.csv | parallel --progress -j +0 'exec >>path_count.csv; echo -n {},; pdfgrep -c [^_] {};'
```

Comment: Nice, although I have to deal with the formatting in the file "path_count". I have multiple echo output and then the pdfgrep output. parallel -k and parallel --group did not work, in various combination with 'echo -n' and/or just 'echo'. Thanks.

Comment: @AlvinDas Do you want each instance to be redirected to another file?